# How to adjust/change TScrollbox Scrollbar width in Delphi

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, vcl

Is there a way to temporarily change the `TScrollbox` Scrollbar width on runtime?

I'm using Delphi XE8.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1432704/62576) didn't help?

Comment: How did you try it, and how did it not work? You need to explain how your question is not a duplicate of the one I linked. If you can't, it *is* a duplicate and this question will be closed as such.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't see how this isn't a duplicate of [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432704/how-do-i-change-the-width-of-a-scrollbar). You seem to have asked the same question, and the other question already establishes that the answer is essentially *no*. Feel free to [edit] your question to clarify how yours is different. Once you do, other site users can vote to re-open your question. (If you convince one of [the 28 people with a gold delphi badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/122/delphi), then you only need one vote.)